# how do I create a clickable table data in a single cell from a table with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example, I want to open a modal with data from a cell in my table

I get a value from my input field

```
 <input type="text" id="id">
```

and then when it goes in a table cell, I can click it to open a modal. kind of like an anchor tag to call the modal.

```
var cel0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
cel0.innerHTML = id;
```

how do I rewrite this code?